# Curl Response with JQ parising error : parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9

Tags: curl, jq

I ran into this issue and didn't find any reference on stackoverflow, someone may find this useful... Saving a json response of curl to a variable with -i flag may yield unexpected result.

```
jq --version
jq-1.5

curl --version
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-w65-mingw32)
```

## Problem

Save curl response to a variable json with -i flag

`json=$(curl http://www.jsonresourcehere.com -i)`

echo output will show json result

`echo $json`

however, performing a jq filter will yields... parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9

```
echo $json | jq '.property'
parse eror: Invalid numeric literal at line1, column 9
```

Comment: The `-i` flag includes header data (non-json) in the output. If you try to pipe that into `jq`, it wouldn't know what to do with it since it's expecting json...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

> remove the -i flag

Solution courtesy of https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1119